# Ternary operator not working as expected

Tags: c#

I am using this code for displaying result as even or odd instead of true and false here:

```
Console.WriteLine(" is " + result == true ? "even" : "odd");
```

Therefore i am using ternary operator , but it is throwing error, some syntax problem is here but i am unable to catching it . 
Thanks in Advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplicationForTesting
    {
        delegate int Increment(int val);
        delegate bool IsEven(int v);

 class lambdaExpressions
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

          Increment Incr = count => count + 1;

          IsEven isEven = n => n % 2 == 0;


           Console.WriteLine("Use incr lambda expression:");
           int x = -10;
           while (x <= 0)
           {
               Console.Write(x + " ");
               bool result = isEven(x);
               Console.WriteLine(" is " + result == true ? "even" : "odd");
               x = Incr(x);
           }
```

Comment: because, there is no return in the function. you expect bool to be returned from IsEven (just guess). Easiset solution, just double click on the row in Visual Studio, and it will bring you on **exact** line where error happens.

Comment: And the error message did not help you?

Comment: @leppie, Error is "" Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'bool' ""

Comment: You can also replace `result == true` with `result` for brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplicationForTesting
{
    delegate int Increment(int val);
    delegate bool IsEven(int v);

 class lambdaExpressions
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      Increment Incr = count => count + 1;

      IsEven isEven = n => n % 2 == 0;


       Console.WriteLine("Use incr lambda expression:");
       int x = -10;
       while (x <= 0)
       {
           Console.Write(x + " ");
           bool result = isEven(x);
           Console.WriteLine(" is " + (result == true ? "even" : "odd"));
           x = Incr(x);
       }
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at the error you are getting:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
>   'bool'

That is because of the missing parentheses. It is concatenating string and bool value, which results in a string value, and you can't compare it against a `bool`.

To fix it do:

```
Console.WriteLine(" is " + (result == true ? "even" : "odd"));
```

Further clarification.

```
bool result = true;
string strTemp = " is " + result;
```

The above statement is a valid statement and results in a string, `is True`, so your statement currently looks like:

```
Console.WriteLine(" is True" == true ? "even" : "odd");
```

The above comparison between a string and bool is invalid, hence you get the error.

Answer (score 4):

You need parentheses. `" is " + (result ? "even" : "odd" );`

The ternary operator has a lower precendence then the concententation (see the [precendence table at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)).

Your original code says combine `" is " + result` and then compare to `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Operator + has higher priority than ==. To fix it, simply put parenthesis around the ternary expresion:

```
Console.WriteLine(" is " + (result == true ? "even" : "odd"));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because of **[operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**. Your expression

```
" is " + result == true ? "even" : "odd"
```

gets interpreted as

```
(" is " + result) == true ? "even" : "odd"
```

because `+` has a higher priority than `==`. Use parentheses or a separate variable to avoid this behaviour.

```
" is " + (result == true ? "even" : "odd")
```

or

```
var evenOrOdd = result == true ? "even" : "odd";
... " is " + evenOrOdd ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine(" is {0}", result ? "even" : "odd");
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss a parenthesis:

```
Console.WriteLine(" is " + (result == true ? "even" : "odd"));
```

The compiler probably complains about `" is " + result`, and you can't add a string and a bool. By adding the parenthesis you group the expressions property, and the compiler is happy. And you too.